# How to create custom model binder for Mongodb ObjectId in Nancy?

Tags: mongodb, web, nancy

In asp.net mvc I did it like this.

```
public class ObjectIdBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var result = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
            return new ObjectId(result.AttemptedValue);
        }
    }
```

How would I do that in Nancy?
Also how do you register it in bootstrapper? code sample?

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up creating an extension to Nancy's Request class.
I created a new Body method that takes a type and uses Json.Net contract to
bind any property in the model that is type ObjectId.

```
public static class BodyBinderExtension
    {
        public static T Body<T>(this Request request)
        {
            request.Body.Position = 0;
            string bodyText;
            using (var bodyReader = new StreamReader(request.Body))
            {
                bodyText = bodyReader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new ObjectIDContractResolver()
            };

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(bodyText);
        }
    }
```